# Angular Typescript extending a class with private service declarations

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

- I've got a page (Component).
- In the code for that that page, I'm making an object of Class B; as I make it, I want to pass it some properties to initialize it (edit flag, an ID, etc.)
- Class B extends Class A.
- Both class A and class B need some services like MatSnackBar, AuthService, and some data services.
- **in order to add services to a class, you declare them as private in the constructor** (can you see where I'm going with this?)

**THE QUESTION: How do I pass parameters to class B that then get passed to class A?**

normally in class A, I'd declare the constructor - I added optional to my services so that I don't have to pass them in?

```
export Class A { 
constructor(id: number, editFlag: boolean, 
@Optional() private snackBar: MatSnackBar, @Optional() private auth: AuthService, @Optional private dataService: DataService, etc...)
```

that does seem to work...

**But then** in Class B, I need to declare a similar constructor:

```
export Class B extends A { 
    constructor(id: number, editFlag: boolean,  
        @Optional() private snackBar: MatSnackBar, @Optional() private auth: AuthService, @Optional 
        private dataService: DataService, etc...) 
    {
        super(id, editFlag);
    }
}
```

It initially didn't work. 
I had to declare the private parameters protected to get it to compile, and i had to call `super(id, editFlag, snackBar, auth, ...)` and... that doesn't seem to work either, since the objects don't seem to pass in.

Is there another way to declare my private services, or is there another way to pass in parameters? Or do I need to make set/get methods to set the parameters and trigger the things that need to happen based on them?

Comment: Class inheritance should honestly be avoided as much as reasonably possible in an angular setting. But you’re Gona have to make the public.

Comment: Why should we avoid inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it.

On the base class, I made `protected` members to hold the services that I want to pass in. I pass them into an instance of Class B, and then from there to the `super()`; the protected status of the member variables lets inheritors but not outsiders use them.

I instantiate the object from my page like this:

```
this.myB = new B(anId, true, snackBar, auth, strService, logger);
```

and in Class B

```
  constructor(idReview: number, editing: boolean, snackBar: MatSnackBar,
              auth: AuthService,  strService: StrService, logger: LoggerService) {
    super(idReview, editing, snackBar, auth, strService, logger);
```

and Class A's declaration

```
export class A extends UnsubscribeOnDestroyAdapter{
  id: number;
  editing: boolean = false;

  protected snackBar: MatSnackBar;

  protected auth: AuthService;
  protected strService: StrService;
  protected logger: LoggerService ;

  constructor(idReview: number, editing: boolean, snackBar: MatSnackBar,
               auth: AuthService,  strService: StrService,
               logger: LoggerService) {
    super();

    this.id = idReview;
    this.editing = editing;
    this.snackBar = snackBar;

    this.auth = auth;
    this.strService = strService;
    this.logger = logger;
}
```

Works!

Thanks to [Alain Chautard](https://stackoverflow.com/story/achautard) for the solution idea!